# WebKit CSS 3 for Mozilla

Tags: webkit, css, mozilla, opacity

What is the equivalent of

```
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s linear;
```

in *-moz*?

I tried replacing *-webkit* with *-moz*, but nothing happened. I even tried extending it to -moz-transition-property/duration, but with no success.

Comment: nowadays firefox supports the transition property without any prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn’t one. CSS animation properties like `transition` were pretty much invented by Apple (although I think they’ve submitted them for inclusion on CSS3), and they’ve only been implemented in WebKit so far.

There is some support in the nightly builds of Firefox though: http://blog.mozbox.org/post/2009/10/12/Some-new-demos

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will probably have to use jquery but this is not what i wanted :(

Comment: Aw. You should ask Mozilla for your money back.

Answer (score 2):

[Try it in Firefox 3.7 (Gecko 1.9)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-transition).

Comment: I never looked at those boxes because i thought they would be about older versions(at what point it was enabled) not when it would come. Thanks :)